# Модернизация небольшой локалки - интеграция с Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

Что имеем сейчас: сеть сейчас [image]  Интернет идет по шнурку до машины с двумя сетевыми картами и `CentOS` на борту. На этой же машине стоит прокси, `iptables`, почта (`dovecot+postfix`), `dns`-сервер (хотя насчет `dns` не уверен, там перенаправление какое-то чтоли), в общем-то всё. Он же, соответственно, выступает шлюзом. Далее от второй сетевки проводок идет в свич, и от свича до клиентских компьютеров и ещё до другого сервера (файлового) с одной сетевой картой.  Файловый сервер поднят на `Win Server 2003` - роли `Wins` и, собственно, файлопомойка.  Идея такая: так как у нас во-первых текучка кадров достаточно такая хорошая, во-вторых некоторых директор садит постоянно за разные компьютеры - человек один день может за одной машиной поработать, второй день за другой, порой приходится для этого специально ещё пользователей в систему добавлять, в общем решил я, что AD был бы идеальным вариантом в этой сети.  Теперь, собственно, ситуация, почему я решил написать здесь. Этим летом я изучал `AD`, думал на другую работу уйти, но много чего не понравилось, решил заняться этой сетью. Какие-то знания по `AD` получил (по книжке для экзамена на сертификат `MCTS` от мелкософта), но тем не менее практики практически не было.  Что хочу - машину с `Win server 2003` сделать контроллером домена (идеально конечно было бы переехать на сервер 2008, я на нем обучался, но пока только 2003), там сделать помимо файлопомойки ещё сервер `AD`. И дальше варианты - либо оставлять раздающий интернет сервер линуксовый, с почтой, и проси, а на вин сервер только `AD`, либо вообще от линуксового отказаться и поставить две сетевые на машину с `Win Server` и поставить там `AD`, почту (как я понимаю, почта на вин это `exchange`?), соответственно, инет. Маршрутизацию пакетов там я не знаю, встроенными какими-нибудь средствами делать, если есть возможность такая.   Плюс ещё вопрос - текучка кадров то большая довольно, но все равно у некоторых свои машины есть. В плане `AD` - юзерам же можно будет сидеть под удаленным аккаунтом, но некоторые файлы хранить на локальном компьютере?  И ещё один момент - на лине сейчас в `iptables` прописан адрес для соединения видимо `VPNки` где-то, или просто туннеля по `GRE` протоколу. Там для программы нужно одной. В вин сервер есть такое? (Ну точнее в вин сервер то наверняка это имеется, просто насколько просто или сложно это реализовать?)  На данный момент там стоит `Core i5 750`, 4 гига `RAM`. Места очень много (терабайта 4, плюс ещё 2 скоро присоединится). Потянет ли такая конфигурация `AD`+Почта+Файлопомойка+еще какие-нибудь сервисы?  В общем, как лучше мне реализовать это все дело?Тут я побольше описал свои вопросы и что мне непонятно

Comment: Кто ещё сюда заглянет - мой же вопрос из комментария: как быть с DNS непосредственно у меня в сети? Т.е. на виртуалках то тут все без проблем, но на маршрутизаторе не стоит DNS, сравнить не могу значит. А вот в реальной сети есть на шлюзе dns is.SOMEDOMAIN.ru. И мне получается на контроллере домена какой DNS делать? Чето типа dc.is.SOMEDOMAIN.ru или просто is.SOMEDOMAIN.ru (Я еще всем технологиям обучаюсь и c DNS я разбираюсь больше в общем плане, чем в плане подстройки-настройке. Он на шлюзе уже был настроен до меня).

Comment: И чето зараза - групповые политики работать не желают. Мало того, что пришлось отдельно поставить gpmc (кстати командой Выполнить -> gpmc.msc вылазит ошибка, только из Пуск->Администрирование можно выполнить), так ещё в этой консоли если тыкнуть на групповую политику и кликнуть Edit, то ругается, что нет такой проги gpedit.msc. Можно только консоли GPO добавить политику и в своей консоли добавить редактор НУЖНОЙ политики... эх, Win server 2008 удобней как-то, зараза, но выбирать не приходится:)

Comment: Всё, админы кончились?:)

Comment: :) вообще, проблемы с запуском оснасток наводят на мысль о каком-то косяке при установке всего этого великолепия. Может быть в системных логах есть какая-то информация по этому поводу? Я имею в виду не установку, а запуск оснасток. Появляется что-нибудь, после ошибки при запуске?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имхо, лучше оставить линуховый шлюз, а на сервере с win2003 поднять только AD + DNS. То, что на нем будет еще и файлопомойка уже само по себе не очень хорошо, а если еще и муршрутизацию и прочее туда прикручивать... чревато последствиями нехорошими. В идеале КД должен только и быть, что КД.По поводу текучки пользователей и того, что они часто работают на разных машинах - самый лучший вариант, по-моему, это перемещаемые профили. Т.е. фактически пользовательские данные хранятся на сервере, и на какой бы машине пользователь ни залогинился, он будет заходить в свой профиль. Единственное "но" - майкрософт не рекомендует при таком раскладе хранить файлы Outlook (*.pst) на сервере, типа он должен локально размещаться.

Comment: В общем-то да, перемещаемые профили тоже неплохо, только вопрос такой - а чем хранение их на том же сервере будет отличаться от AD. Наверное вопрос для многих тупым покажется, но мне казалось, что для этого AD и делают. Или я не совсем правильно эту технологию расцениваю? Или они с помощью AD и делаются?

Comment: Вторая сетевая не нужна - сервер не будет использоваться как шлюз. Эксченж на КД - имхо плохая идея. К тому же, если есть уже работающий почтовик.  В общем-то поднимаете КД на сервере, заводите в домен все машины, если DNS получается через DHCP, соответственно правите конфиги, чтоб правильные настройки раздавались, создаете пользователей, если надо, то локальные профили можно перенести в доменные какой-нибудь программкой типа ProfileWizard. Профили делаете перемещаемыми.  Все что работает (почтовик, прокси и т.п.) я бы не трогал :)

Comment: Просто exchange хотел для более простой настройки пользователей для почты сделать. Вариант такой - из менее реальных) Можно ли сделать такую штуку - в AD добавляю пользователя, пароль для него, запускается скрипт, который по SSH коннектится к линуксу и там тоже этого же пользователя с этим же паролем добавляет?И в AD же можно всем по дефолту программы ставить, так вот - можно ли например, чтобы у юзера стоял The Bat тоже с уже сразу введеными его данными? Exchange бы просто получается сразу два этих вопроса прибил) Но раз лучше его отдельно делать, то правда пусть остается то, что уже есть)

Comment: А скажите как быть с DNS непосредственно у меня в сети? Т.е. на виртуалках то тут все без проблем, но на маршрутизаторе не стоит DNS, сравнить не могу значит. А вот в реальной сети есть на шлюзе dns is.SOMEDOMAIN.ru. И мне получается на контроллере домена какой DNS делать? Чето типа dc.is.SOMEDOMAIN.ru или просто is.SOMEDOMAIN.ru (Я еще всем технологиям обучаюсь и c DNS я разбираюсь больше в общем плане, чем в плане подстройки-настройке. Он на шлюзе уже был настроен до меня).  И ещё вопрос какой-то был, но пока запамятовал.

Comment: По поводу DNSа. Останавливаете DNS на шлюзе, ставите на вин2003 DNS, AD и что еще захотите (имя домена используете старое), настраиваете DNS-форвардинг на провайдерские серверы, в таком случае, если имя в ЛАНе не найдено, запрос уйдет на провайдера. Если настойки сети раздаются по DHCP, правите конфиг DHCP-сервера, чтобы он раздавал нужный ip dns'а, заводите машины в домен.По скриптам и предварительной настройке The Bat, к сожалению, не подскажу.

Comment: Спасибо. DNS обязательно на шлюзе надо остановить, или можно поддомен на AD DC сделать? И ещё появились проблемы с GPO - не работают. Выше в комментарии к теме написал, и в самой теме ссылку сделал на тему на форуме, где я побольше проблему расписал

Answer (score 0):

С такими вопросами как задаёт автор рановато внедрять AD в работающую сеть. Лучше дома потренеруйтесь. Больше половины вопросов не глупы а не в тему:

1.Контроллер домена не должен быть один, резервный обязательно и ТЧК.2.Даже резервный контроллер домена не должен быть шлюзом, почтовиком... и желательно не размещать на КД файлопомойку (последнее не критично но не желательно)3.Не забывайте про виртуализацию, но тут лучше 2008 r2.4.Забейте на 2003 сервер, сегодня уже совсем другие времена, если внедрять то только 2008r2.5.Подумайте о том, что этот проект достаточно серьёзный и трудоёмкий для того чтоб задуматься о внедрении сервера терминалов и тонких клиентов, если конечно пользователи юзают чисто офисные приложения, в такой конфигурации всегда есть возможность некоторые рабочие места оставить на полноценных PC.

В последнем случае Вы получите несколько компьютеров для разворачивания на них серверной инфраструктуры, тобишь основной и резервный контроллеры домена, почтовик можно вынести на отдельную машину, шлюз оставьте линуху, если exchange тоже лучше на отдельную машину ставить, ну хотя бы виртуальную а желательно физическую. Свой 750-й юзайте как сервер терминалов, самое то для него.

Windows это дорого, гораздо дороже чем кажется на первый взгляд. Но оно того стоит, в принципе.